# tar command fails on bigsize(191 GB) file

Tags: clipboard, tar

In Ubuntu, tar command fails while copying bigfile of size 191GB from disk to tape device and gives below error.

```
tar -cvf /dev/st0 /mtpt/ntfs
```

in /mtpt/ntfs, we have files of size 2gb to 5gb and they are getting copied and while copying filesize of 191gb it fails.

on the monitor we get below

```
tar: /dev/st0: Cannot write: Input/Output error
```

And In Kern log we get below error message -

---

```
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.927292]  rport-5:0-2: 
blocked FC remote port time out: removing target and saving binding Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.960315] st0: Error e0000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0xe). 
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.960677] scsi 5:0:2:0: 
rejecting I/O to dead device 
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.977006] st0: Error 10000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0x1). 
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.977009] st0: Error on write filemark. 
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162046.993200] scsi 5:0:2:0: 
rejecting I/O to dead device 
Aug  2 13:12:12 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162047.009194] st0: Error 10000 (driver bt 0x0, host bt 0x1). 
Aug  2 13:12:15 DigitalAssetMgmt kernel: [162050.307793] scsi 5:0:2:0: 
Sequential-Access IBM      ULT3580-HH4      B171 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
```

---

Please help us.
Thanks and Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 2):

GNU manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Formats.html#Formats) says that there is a limit of 8GB for file sizes, so you should be ok there, unless you happen to have a file bigger than that among the other smaller ones you mention. If you need larger files you could change the tar format to POSIX with the  `tar --format` option.

If that's not the case, are you reaching the end of the tape cartridge perhaps? That does seem more likely from the messages you see, it seems to me.